# How to use a database in influx with a dot in its name?

Tags: sql, influxdb

When I try to reach my database, 'EUNL.F' there only comes back an error.

```
use exampledb
```

Works fine

but

```
use EUNL.F
```

returns: EUNL doesn't exist.

How do I include the dot to the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For influxdb, you should [escape](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/#special-characters) `dot` character with `\`

```
use EUNL\.F
use "EUNL\.F"
```